# Кивнуть на нас - можно?

Tags: предлоги, управление

> Он подбежал к владыке, залопотал, заюлил, потом начал активно
>   жестикулировать и припрыгивать. Владыка, даже не посмотрев в его
>   сторону, отошёл к столу справа и **кивнул на нас**. Нас снова усадили
>   и снова обнесли ракией.

У ФМ ещё кручее:

> *Как нарочно, Стебельков хитро и гадко осклабился и украдкой кивнул мне на князя.* Ф. М. Достоевский, «Подросток», 1875 г.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, если этим кивком дают знак *другому* (здесь, видимо, тем, кто должен усаживать гостей). "Годность" самого выражения видна из такой присказки: "Иван кивает на Петра, а Пётр на Ивана".

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что можно.

В словаре Кузнецова:
КИВА́ТЬ, -а́ю, -а́ешь; нсв.
**2. на кого-что.** Указывать движением головы в сторону кого-либо, чего-либо.

*— Посмотрите на него: не правда ли, в нем что-то есть? — говорила она своим друзьям, **кивая на мужа** и как бы желая объяснить, почему это она вышла за простого, очень обыкновенного и ничем не замечательного человека* (А. П. Чехов. Попрыгунья).

*Когда створки раскрылись, он **кивнул на желтое светило*** (В. Шалыгин. Бессмертие наемника).